# how to move to the end of current cell?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

in org mode table. I have a cell with many words, and and to append more words to the end. But how to quick move to the end of current cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `org-forward-sentence` is bound to `M-e`. When inside a table, it will jump to the end of the current field (calling `org-table-end-of-field` as @JeanPierre noted in his answer).

All table related keybindings are listed [in the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-table-editor.html#Built_002din-table-editor).

Answer (score 1):

In org-mode, table cells are called **field**s. `C-h a org field` outputs a list of commands related to org tables fields, including:

```
org-table-end-of-field        M-x ... RET
   Move to the end of the current table field.
```

It does not seem to be bound to any key by default.